Understanding Normal integration with the Fourier shift theorem.
I'm struggling to understand this paper: http://purplebark.net/mra/papers/spiral-dic-jmic-preprint-sep03.pdf
Firstly, what are $\Phi_x$ and $\Phi_y$ ? It says that they are Fourier transformed functions as denoted by the capitalisation. Does that mean that they are the 1D Fourier transform of $\Phi$ in the x and y directions respectively?
Secondly, how do they go from equation 5 to equation 6? I don't think I understand the steps they haven't shown here.

